# What is a good practice to save a lone text?

Tags: symfony

I am developing a website that has "normal" pages with entity `Page`, therefore stored in a database and "special" pages, such as homepage, contact page, etc.

What is the best practice to store the content of these special pages? Their structure is always different, I can't create an entity `SpecialPage`, it makes no sense.

My ideas so far:

- One entity for each page (yucky): `HomePage`, `ContactPage`, …
- Save it in text files of some sort (also yucky): `homePage.xml`, `contactPage.yml`, …

Comment: Do you want to save this text so it can be content manageable by users of your application? Otherwise it's just a template.

Comment: Of course, it must be user managable! Silly me not to precise it.

Comment: In what respect are the pages different from each other? Btw, I agree with *Guillaume Fache* that using Twig and template inheritance would be the better approach here.

Comment: Examples of differences: **home page** has a text and an author, **contact page** has a text and an e-mail address, **description page** has 3 sections, each with a title and a text. If I consider all the pages to be similar, I should build an entity with 3 texts (2 nullable), 3 titles (all nullable), a user (nullable) and an e-mail address (nullable). And I use some of the data for some pages and some other for other pages. I don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to store what seems to be html pages in database. Entities are meant to reflect the model of your application. The folder Resources/views is meant to store all your views. I think that's where you should keep them.

You can use twig inheritance to make DRY pages, and if you have single special pages, you create them one by one, that's no problem.

Hope this helps.